# Looking for a good private, free and secure wiki web application

Tags: wiki

I know I can just install [MediaWiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki), but I prefer not to do the maintainance. What website offers **free**, **private** and **secure** wikis?

**Edit** -
From what I've looked at so far, [Google Sites](https://sites.google.com/) is the only one that fits the bill. However, I was aiming for something less featured, where editing and creating articles would be faster (e.g. MediaWiki style).

Comment: And are the abilities of Google Wave a superset of a wiki? Is it what I'm looking for?

Comment: Please define private and secure.  Do you mean that it is well patched and maintained, do you mean that it is encrypted, do you mean that it has a strong authentication/access controls system?

Comment: @Zoredache - SSL

Answer (score 4):

You may already know this, but what about  [Google Sites](https://sites.google.com/).

Its free, secure and provides private sites.

Comment: I didn't know they offer wikis, thanks! Although it has some nice features over simpler wikis like MediaWiki, I miss that simplicity. I want a site where I can create & link new pages fast, and the interface for doing this on Google Sites is a bit too slow for my taste.

Comment: Yes, sometimes it is slow. There was a similar question on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143321/best-hosted-wiki-solution-for-private-wikis

Answer (score 3):

So you want free, secure, private, and have it hosted by someone else? Myself I would probably go with a site that offers free hosting that supports PHP and install PmWiki and setup access control on the wiki then.

You could also check out the sites on this list:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_wiki_farms

Comment: I would also prefer it be managed by someone else. Yes, I have lots of requirements :)

Comment: Sorry, I thought you linked to "comparison of wiki software"

Comment: I looked through this list, unfortunately haven't found anything that answers the criteria.

Answer (score 3):

What about [Wiki On A Stick](http://stickwiki.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements are a hard combination to get: free, hosted, secure and private? For free, you can bet it won't be private, or you'll have to deal with advertisement. Hosts need to make some business out of it, y'know.

Personally, I'd go with Wayne's solution: get free hosting that supports php and install a database-less wiki on it (I personally consider DokuWiki a simple and good option).

Still, you may want to visit http://www.wikimatrix.org/ and try to find the wiki that best fits your needs.

Comment: I've got no problem with ads :)